# Newcommand for each letter

Tags: macros, characters

I am using custom commands to facilitate both writing and reading LaTeX equations, such as :

```
\newcommand{\bbA}{\mathbb{A}}
\newcommand{\bbB}{\mathbb{B}}
\newcommand{\bbC}{\mathbb{C}}
% etc...
\newcommand{\mcA}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\mcB}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{\mcC}{\mathcal{C}}
% etc...
\newcommand{\msA}{\mathscr{A}}
\newcommand{\msB}{\mathscr{B}}
\newcommand{\msC}{\mathscr{C}}
% etc...
\newcommand{\mfA}{\mathfrak{A}}
\newcommand{\mfB}{\mathfrak{B}}
\newcommand{\mfC}{\mathfrak{C}}
% etc...
\newcommand{\mfa}{\mathfrak{a}}
\newcommand{\mfb}{\mathfrak{b}}
\newcommand{\mfc}{\mathfrak{c}}
% etc...
```

However, this takes up 130 lines of code in the file header (that I, fortunately, didn't write by hand, I made a program to do so, which is why I'm quite positive there's a solution to my problem)...

TeXStudio allows me to enclose it between `%BEGIN_FOLD` and `%END_FOLD` comments, that make me able to collapse this whole mess. However, I have two concerns :

1. The `%BEGIN_FOLD` and `%END_FOLD` thing doesn't collapse by default, it gets expanded back upon re-opening the file. Moreover, I'm not sure this isn't a TeXStudio-only feature.
2. Does it affect compiling time ? I don't know how the compiler handles `\newcommand`s, but if it has to re-define and re-compile them all every time, I'm sure there's room for improvement.

Thus, I am asking the following :

> Is there a way to compact each block of 26 commands to a single command ?

*In fine*, I'd like not having to do something like `\bb{A}`, `\ms{A}`, *etc*, that is, I don't just want an alias to these commands. What I am willing to achieve is to get rid of these curly brackets, for two reasons :

1. As I've been using these commands for a few years now, muscle memory is going to be problematic.
2. Typing `Alt Gr`+`4`, `Alt Gr`+`+`, going `Left`, typing the letter and going `Right` again takes quite some time : this is the reason why I originally made these commands.

I'm not a LaTeX guru like some of you who already helped me a ton, and perhaps I just missed something when trying to find another approach than my "brute force" 130 lines... Thank you for your kind replies !

Comment: the braces are optional why not `\newcommand\mf{\mathfrak}`  then use `\mf A`defining all the extra commands seems totally unnecessary.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thats wonderful! thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Much less than 130 lines of code.

The idea is to do a loop in the given range; I use the alphabetic constants, so, for instance, `A` corresponds to 63, but it's not necessary to know it. The loop index is denoted by `##1` and will take in turn the ASCII number of the letters; with the help of `\char_generate:nn` we can generate the corresponding character. The definition is “expanded”, so we need not to expand the command, which is obtained by prefixing it with `\exp_not:N`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definealphabet}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = prefix, #2 = command, #3 = start, #4 = end
  \int_step_inline:nnn { `#3 } { `#4 }
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpx { #1 \char_generate:nn { ##1 }{ 11 } }
     {
      \exp_not:N #2 { \char_generate:nn { ##1 } { 11 } }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definealphabet{bb}{\mathbb}{A}{Z}
\definealphabet{mc}{\mathcal}{A}{Z}
\definealphabet{mf}{\mathfrak}{A}{Z}
\definealphabet{mf}{\mathfrak}{a}{z}

\begin{document}

$\bbA+\mcB+\mfS+\mfz$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more general method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definealphabet}{smmm}
 {% #1 = star for lowercase , #2 = prefix, #3 = suffix, #4 = math alphabet
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {
    \physicsstudent_definealphabet:nnnnn { #2 } { #3 } { `a } { `z } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \physicsstudent_definealphabet:nnnnn { #2 } { #3 } { `A } { `Z } { #4 }
   }
 }

\msg_new:nnn { physicsstudent/definealphabet } { existing }
 {
  Command ~ '\exp_not:c { #1 #2 #3 }' ~ already ~ defined
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \physicsstudent_definealphabet:nnnnn
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnn { #3 } { #4 }
   {
    \__physicsstudent_definealphabet:ennn { \char_generate:nn { ##1 } { 12 } } { #1 } { #2 } { #5 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__physicsstudent_definealphabet:nnnn
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cTF { #2 #1 #3 }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnnnn { physicsstudent/definealphabet } { existing } { #2 } { #1 } { #3 }
   }
   {
    \cs_new_protected:cpn { #2 #1 #3 } { #4 { #1 } }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__physicsstudent_definealphabet:nnnn { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\let\Bbb\relax % after seeing the warning
\definealphabet{}{bb}{\mathbb}
\definealphabet{frak}{}{\mathfrak}
\definealphabet*{frak}{}{\mathfrak}

\begin{document}

$\Abb+\frakA-\frakb$

\end{document}
```

You can specify either a prefix or a suffix (or even both). With the *-version, the lowercase alphabet is defined.

If you leave out the `\let\Bbb\relax` line, you'll get a warning

```
Package physicsstudent/definealphabet Warning: Command '\Bbb ' already defined
```

Examine the log file for such cases and decide whether the command *can* be safely redefined (with `\Bbb` it's possible, because it's only defined for compatibility with very old documents) or if a change in prefix/suffix is better.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

The command `\DEFINEbbANDmcANDmsANDmfLOOP` is intended to process an undelimited argument which consists of exactly one token. It checks whether its argument's first token's meaning equals the meaning of the `\relax`-primitive.
If so, it swallows the following action via `\@gobble`.
If not so it assumes that the argument is a single character token denoting a *⟨letter⟩* and performs the following action via `\@firstofone`:

- define the macro `\bb⟨letter⟩` to expand to `\mathbb{⟨letter⟩}`
- define the macro `\mc⟨letter⟩` to expand to `\mathcal{⟨letter⟩}`
- define the macro `\ms⟨letter⟩` to expand to `\mathscr{⟨letter⟩}`
- define the macro `\mf⟨letter⟩` to expand to `\mathfrakr{⟨letter⟩}`
- call itself again.

The concept of a macro calling itself again for applying the same action to another argument is called tail-recursion.

(For defining the macros I have implemented a little helper-macro `\CmdName` which works as follows:

`\CmdName⟨stuff without braces⟩{macroname}` → `⟨stuff without braces⟩\macroname`.

Examples:

`\CmdName\newcommand*{foobar}...` → `\newcommand*\foobar...`.

I use `\CmdName` when I am not in the mood for typing `\expandafter` and `\csname..\endcsname` so often. ;-)  )

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\CmdName{\long\def\CmdName#1#{\romannumeral0\innerCmdName{#1}}}%
\newcommand\innerCmdName[2]{\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname #2\endcsname}{ #1}}%
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\DEFINEbbANDmcANDmsANDmfLOOP[1]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
  {%
    \CmdName\newcommand*{bb#1}{\mathbb{#1}}%
    \CmdName\newcommand*{mc#1}{\mathcal{#1}}%
    \CmdName\newcommand*{ms#1}{\mathscr{#1}}%
    \CmdName\newcommand*{mf#1}{\mathfrak{#1}}%
    \DEFINEbbANDmcANDmsANDmfLOOP
  }%
}%
\makeatother

% Now for each of the letters define \bb<letter>, \mc<letter>, \ms<letter> and \mf<letter>:

\DEFINEbbANDmcANDmsANDmfLOOP abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\relax

\begin{document}

\show\bba
\show\mca
\show\msa
\show\mfa

\show\bbb
\show\mcb
\show\msb
\show\mfb

%  . 
%  .
%  .
%  .

\show\bbY
\show\mcY
\show\msY
\show\mfY

\show\bbZ
\show\mcZ
\show\msZ
\show\mfZ

\end{document}
```

---

If you like, you can apply tail-recursion with a macro `\Definealphabet`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\DEFINEALPHABETLOOP[3]{%
  \ifx\relax#3\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
  {\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname#1#3\endcsname{#2{#3}}%
   \DEFINEALPHABETLOOP{#1}{#2}}%
}%
\newcommand\Definealphabet[2]{%
  \DEFINEALPHABETLOOP{#1}{#2}abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\relax
}%
\makeatother


\Definealphabet{bb}{\mathbb}
\Definealphabet{mc}{\mathcal}
\Definealphabet{ms}{\mathscr}
\Definealphabet{mf}{\mathfrak}


\begin{document}

\show\bba
% ...
\show\bbz


\show\mca
% ...
\show\mcz


\show\msa
% ...
\show\msz


\show\mfa
% ...
\show\mfz


\end{document}
```

---

If you need a TeX-⟨*number*⟩-quantity which denotes the character-code of a charcter in the internal character-representation-scheme of TeX, you can use alphabetic constants.
E.g., both `` `A `` and `` `\A `` denotes the character code of the character `A`.
The further is not "`\lowercase`-proof".
The latter in the context of macro-programming might not be proof against the control sequence token behind `` ` `` being `\outer`.
Also be aware that TeX scans for one optional space with the last token of an alphabetic constant.

Thus, if you like, you can as well implement a tail-recursive loop, where `\csname..\endcsname` is combined with `\lccode`/`\lowercase`-trickery for looping over the alphabet, and where you can specify slash-separated phrases for the math-alphabet-command to call and for the names of the commands to define the prefix before the alphabetical letter and the postfix behind the alphabetical letter:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\@ifdefinable\SlashFirstOfThree{\long\def\SlashFirstOfThree#1/#2/#3/{#1}}%
\@ifdefinable\SlashArgBetweenSecondAndThirdOfThree{\long\def\SlashArgBetweenSecondAndThirdOfThree#1#2/#3/#4/{#3#1#4}}%
\newcommand\DefineAlphabetsLoop[1]{\DefineAlphabetsLoopInner{`\A}#1\relax}%
\newcommand\DefineAlphabetsLoopInner[2]{%
  % #1 - character-code of character wherefore macro is to be defined; #2 - slash-separated triple of phrases:
  % of pattern  
  % <math-alphabet-macro to call>/<prefix before alphabet-letter of name of macro to define>/<prefix after alphabet-letter of name of macro to define>
  \ifx\relax#2\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi{%
    \ifnum#1>\@firstofone{`\z} \expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi
    %\@ifundefined{\SlashArgBetweenSecondAndThirdOfThree{z}#2/}%
    {%
      \begingroup
      \lccode`\m=#1\relax
      \lowercase\expandafter{\expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\SlashFirstOfThree#2/{m}}}%
      {%
         \lowercase{\PassFirstToSecond{m}}%
         {\endgroup\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname\SlashArgBetweenSecondAndThirdOfThree}#2/\endcsname
      }%
      \expandafter\DefineAlphabetsLoopInner\expandafter{\the\numexpr\ifnum#1=`\Z`\a\else(#1)+1\fi\relax}{#2}%
    }{%
      \DefineAlphabetsLoopInner{`\A}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Only prefix:

\DefineAlphabetsLoop{{\mathbb/bb/}{\mathcal/mc/}{\mathscr/ms/}{\mathfrak/mf/}}%

\show\bbA \show\mcA \show\msA \show\mfA
\show\bbB \show\mcB \show\msB \show\mfB
\show\bbY \show\mcY \show\msY \show\mfY
\show\bbZ \show\mcZ \show\msZ \show\mfZ
%  . 
%  .
%  .
%  .
\show\bba \show\mca \show\msa \show\mfa
\show\bbb \show\mcb \show\msb \show\mfb
\show\bby \show\mcy \show\msy \show\mfy
\show\bbz \show\mcz \show\msz \show\mfz

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Only postfix:

% Of course you get: ! LaTeX Error: Command \bbb already defined.
% That's because \bbb was defined by the prevous loop.

\DefineAlphabetsLoop{{\mathbb//bb}{\mathcal//mc}{\mathscr//ms}{\mathfrak//mf}}%

\show\Abb \show\Amc \show\Ams \show\Amf
\show\Bbb \show\Bmc \show\Bms \show\Bmf
\show\Ybb \show\Ymc \show\Yms \show\Ymf
\show\Zbb \show\Zmc \show\Zms \show\Zmf
%  . 
%  .
%  .
%  .
\show\abb \show\amc \show\ams \show\amf
\show\bbb \show\bmc \show\bms \show\bmf
\show\ybb \show\ymc \show\yms \show\ymf
\show\zbb \show\zmc \show\zms \show\zmf

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Both prefix and postfix:

\DefineAlphabetsLoop{{\mathbb/bb/bb}{\mathcal/mc/mc}{\mathscr/ms/ms}{\mathfrak/mf/mf}}%

\show\bbAbb \show\mcAmc \show\msAms \show\mfAmf
\show\bbBbb \show\mcBmc \show\msBms \show\mfBmf
\show\bbYbb \show\mcYmc \show\msYms \show\mfYmf
\show\bbZbb \show\mcZmc \show\msZms \show\mfZmf
%  . 
%  .
%  .
%  .
\show\bbabb \show\mcamc \show\msams \show\mfamf
\show\bbbbb \show\mcbmc \show\msbms \show\mfbmf
\show\bbybb \show\mcymc \show\msyms \show\mfymf
\show\bbzbb \show\mczmc \show\mszms \show\mfzmf

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Of course, instead of having three `\DefineAlphabetsLoop`, you could
% as well have done:
%
% \DefineAlphabetsLoop{%
%                       {\mathbb/bb/}{\mathcal/mc/}{\mathscr/ms/}{\mathfrak/mf/}%
%                       {\mathbb//bb}{\mathcal//mc}{\mathscr//ms}{\mathfrak//mf}%
%                       {\mathbb/bb/bb}{\mathcal/mc/mc}{\mathscr/ms/ms}{\mathfrak/mf/mf}%
%                     }%


\end{document}
```

---

A slightly more generic variant could be:

`\alphabetloop{<stuff>}`  by and by does:  `<stuff>{A}...<stuff>{Z}<stuff>{a}...<stuff>{z}`

and

```latex
\LoopEachOverAlphabet{<stuff prefix>}{<stuff postfix>}{%
    {<stuff 1>}%
    {<stuff 2>}%
    %...
    {<stuff n>}%
}%
```

by and by does

```latex
\alphabetloop{<stuff prefix><stuff 1><stuff postfix>}%
\alphabetloop{<stuff prefix><stuff 2><stuff postfix>}%
...
\alphabetloop{<stuff prefix><stuff n><stuff postfix>}%
```

, which by and by turns into

```latex
<stuff prefix><stuff 1><stuff postfix>{A}...<stuff prefix><stuff 1><stuff postfix>{Z}<stuff prefix><stuff 1><stuff postfix>{a}...<stuff prefix><stuff 1><stuff postfix>{z}%
<stuff prefix><stuff 2><stuff postfix>{A}...<stuff prefix><stuff 2><stuff postfix>{Z}<stuff prefix><stuff 2><stuff postfix>{a}...<stuff prefix><stuff 2><stuff postfix>{z}%
%...
<stuff prefix><stuff n><stuff postfix>{A}...<stuff prefix><stuff n><stuff postfix>{Z}<stuff prefix><stuff n><stuff postfix>{a}...<stuff prefix><stuff n><stuff postfix>{z}%
```

.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\alphabetloop{\alphabetloopinner{`\A}}%
\newcommand\alphabetloopinner[2]{%
  \ifnum#1>\@firstofone{`\z} \expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
  {%
    \begingroup
    \lccode`\m=#1\relax
    \lowercase{\PassFirstToSecond{m}}{\endgroup#2}%
    \expandafter\alphabetloopinner\expandafter{\the\numexpr\ifnum#1=`\Z`\a\else(#1)+1\fi\relax}{#2}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\LoopEachOverAlphabet[3]{\LoopEachOverAlphabetInner{#1}{#2}#3\relax}%
\newcommand\LoopEachOverAlphabetInner[3]{%
  \ifx\relax#3\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi{%
     \alphabetloop{#1#3#2}%
     \LoopEachOverAlphabetInner{#1}{#2}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\definealphabetmacro{%
  \long\def\definealphabetmacro#1/#2/#3/#4{\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter*\csname #2#4#3\endcsname{#1{#4}}}%
}%
\newcommand\DefineAlphabetMacros{%
  \LoopEachOverAlphabet{\definealphabetmacro}{/}%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\showalphabetmacro[3]{%
  \expandafter\show\csname #1#3#2\endcsname
}%


\begin{document}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Only prefix:

\DefineAlphabetMacros{{\mathbb/bb/}{\mathcal/mc/}{\mathscr/ms/}{\mathfrak/mf/}}%

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Only postfix:

% Of course you get: ! LaTeX Error: Command \bbb already defined.
% That's because \bbb was defined by the prevous loop.

\DefineAlphabetMacros{{\mathbb//bb}{\mathcal//mc}{\mathscr//ms}{\mathfrak//mf}}%

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Both prefix and postfix:

\DefineAlphabetMacros{{\mathbb/bb/bb}{\mathcal/mc/mc}{\mathscr/ms/ms}{\mathfrak/mf/mf}}%

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Of course, instead of having three `\DefineAlphabetsLoop`, you could
% as well have done:
%
% \DefineAlphabetMacros{%
%                        {\mathbb/bb/}{\mathcal/mc/}{\mathscr/ms/}{\mathfrak/mf/}%
%                        {\mathbb//bb}{\mathcal//mc}{\mathscr//ms}{\mathfrak//mf}%
%                        {\mathbb/bb/bb}{\mathcal/mc/mc}{\mathscr/ms/ms}{\mathfrak/mf/mf}%
%                      }%

% This does \show  12*52  = 624 times. \bbb is shown twice:

\def\scratch{0}
\LoopEachOverAlphabet{%
  \edef\scratch{\the\numexpr\scratch+1\relax}%
  \message{^^JIteration \scratch:^^J}%
  \showalphabetmacro
}{}{%
  {{bb}{}} {{mc}{}}  {{ms}{}} {{mf}{}}
  {{}{bb}} {{}{mc}}  {{}{ms}} {{}{mf}}
  {{bb}{bb}} {{mc}{mc}}  {{ms}{ms}} {{mf}{mf}}
}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't accept both answers ! Thanks a lot for sharing !

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq Instead of one of the answers I would accept the comment of David Carlisle if that was possible. :-)