# Simplifying commands

Tags: macros

I have a command defined as

```
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to define it in a way that I can write `\mbA` instead `\mb{A}`? One way is to define one by one `\dbA`, `\dbB`, `\dbC`, etc. but I hope there is something straightforward to achieve this.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Newcommand for each letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/564216/5764)

Comment: It's perfectly ok, as far as TeX and LaTeX are concerned, to write `\mb A`, `\mb B`, `\mb C`, etc instead of `\mb{A}`, `\mb{B}`, `\mb{C}`, etc.

Comment: Have a look at [Short names for macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/short-names-for-macros)

Comment: Why not just `\newcommand*\mb{\mathbb}` ?

Comment: @Mico Unfortunately, spacing does not worth not defining \mbA. First, things like \mb A_\mb B does not look nice on editor but more importantly, things like \tilde\mb A does not work.

Comment: @Werner Thank you. I couldn't find the time to check it yet as it does not look very easy but seems like the solution exists.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Then \mbA does not work, right?

Comment: @Jo' No, but `\mb A` does work. If you want `\mbA`/`\mbB`/`\mbC`/... to work, each of these control-word-tokens needs to be defined on its own. You can define a loop which does that for you, e.g., as shown in the [contribution linked by Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660149/simplifying-commands?noredirect=1#comment1642510_660149).